# Automatic call of methods in class

Tags: python, class

I'm learning Python and I'm having a trouble with understanding topic`class`, so
I'd like to ask some questions

- what is the difference between `hash()` and `__hash__()` ?
- when i define functions ( for example `__init__()` ) in `class`, are they called automatically or do I need to call them explicitly  ?
- in `class`, is there a difference in defining a reserved function ( `def __hash__():` ) and my own function ( `def foo():` ) ?

Thank you!

Comment: What source are you using when learning Python? A decent introduction should explain how it works. The question is too broad since answering it adequately would require a large amount of explanation and would serve simply to reproduce material which is easily found in numerous tutorials/books. I am voting to close this question as too broad.

Answer (score 1):

Special methods (sometimes called magic methods) such as `__hash__` and `__new__` are indirectly called through different mechanisms.

For example if you have defined `__hash__` on a class Foo and instantiated object foo of the class:

```
hash(foo)
```

Will call your `__hash__` method.

Another example is `__new__` and `__init__`

```
Foo()
```

Indirectly calls the `__new__` and `__init__` defined on your class.
It will call `__new__` first which should return an instance, the `__init__` method deals with initializing your instance and returns None. You very rarely need to implement `__new__` on your class, unless you want to somehow override the process of instance creation, this is usually done when defining metaclasses or overriding immutable types.

Other types of special methods are used for operator overloading, such as `__eq__`

```
foo==bar
```

Will indirectly call your definition of `__eq__` with the bar argument.

Comment: If you are going to talk about `__new__`, you really should explain `__init__` and why almost always you should be using `__init__` instead of `__new__`.

Comment: I meant `__init__` not `__new__`, thanks for correcting that.